# Get records that have no count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, using

I have had a dig around but still having a problem with this. Below is the table structure:

JOBS

```
jobs_id | title
```

JOBS_APLICATIONS

```
id | jobs_id | user_id | candidate_id | employer_id
```

I have this query..

```
SELECT ja.job_id, COUNT(*) AS count, j.title
FROM job_applications AS ja
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j
ON ja.jobs_id = j.jobs_id
GROUP BY ja.jobs_id
```

But it doesn't return any jobs that have no count e.g '0'. Please how do I change the query to show these?

Comment: without seeing the schema it is quite impossible to answer.

Comment: Your query is okay!!
I think you make some other mistake

Comment: It looks like it should, although the returned j.title is likely to have a meaningless value (which row it comes from is undetermined).

Comment: Miller Koijam. The basic schema is now there. Its just not showing any zero counts. Kickstart, I agree. That will be removed.

Comment: Because you are grouping on job_applications. Try changing to a RIGHT JOIN and grouping on j.jobs_id

Comment: Will there ever be any job_applications that do not refer to a job? If not then just swap the table names around (ie, FROM jobs j LEFT OUTER JOIN job_applications ja )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a normal `JOIN`.

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` keyword returns all rows from both tables.

*Edit: I searched for a MySQL alternative:*

```
(SELECT ja.job_id, COUNT(*) AS count, j.title
FROM job_applications AS ja
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j
ON ja.job_id = j.jobs_id
GROUP BY ja.job_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ja.job_id, COUNT(*) AS count, j.title
FROM job_applications AS ja
RIGHT JOIN jobs AS j
ON ja.job_id = j.jobs_id
WHERE tbl1.col IS NULL
GROUP BY ja.job_id)
```

Didn't had the time to test it..

Comment: mysql does not have `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

I think query has not any issue just it has one extra column title which is not in group by clause.

```
SELECT ja.job_id, COUNT(j.jobs_id) AS count
FROM job_applications AS ja
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs AS j
ON ja.job_id = j.jobs_id
GROUP BY ja.job_id
```

This query will return all the record which is in the job_applications table and count of jobs table bases of link.

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question. The query is fine. After removing the title all was fine.

Thanks for your time.